# Localization of SSRS itself (not the reports)

Tags: reporting-services, localization

I want to localize SSRS *itself* (not the report), but it looks like no one has done or requested something like that before.

I want to translate all the main texts on SSRS page, accessed through such a URL:

```
http://yourssrs.com/reports
```

On such a page you can see links and buttons like "home", "Data view", "search", "Help", "New Folder", "Report Builder" "My Subscriptions" etc.

I want to translate them all. Are there language files for this, or something like that to translate SSRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for this MSDN page: [Solution Design Considerations for Multi-Lingual or Global Deployments (Reporting Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156493%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). The features you mention are mostly Report Manager items (I think), which -according to the mentioned article- are localized based on the client browser language:

> Language and Locale settings in the client browser determine the language resource used for:
>   -    Report Manager
>   -    Report Viewer toolbar
>   -    My Reports folder name
>   -    Localized elements of the report server folder hierarchy and report server content types, when the Report Server Web service is accessed through a browser window.

Comment: You should not have to localize anything manually - as per the information linked to above, the language Report Manager is displayed in is determined by the *client* browser settings, e.g. if your client browser language is French, then you will see Report Manager in French regardless of the language setting of the report server.

Comment: Hello All ! I'm experiencing the opposite of what Nathan said, the clients browsers are in French while Report Manager is showing in English, which is pretty strange and nobody in my team knows why? and it also happened suddenly !

Comment: @ZakariaBelghiti Wow, that's strange. I'm afraid this Q&A is 4 years old, and comments aren't really the best place to ask a follow-up question. I suggest you gather all debug info that would be relevant (language of your desktop and report server OS, browser, .NET framework, SQL Server install, etc etc) and post a new question, linking to this one and explaining how yours is different.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing.
You can do this, even if the user uses another language.

The secret is passing a parameter for the desired language to the ssrs page. 
Then, you can create a http-module, that gets the language from the URL/referrer (note: HTTP misspells referrer as referer)

Example code:

https://github.com/ststeiger/SSRS-Localizer/blob/master/libRequestLanguageChanger/RequestLanguageChanger.cs

(this code also sets the P3P-header, as this is necessary for the SSRS-cookies in IE if the page is iframed from a page on a different domain)

This sets SSRS into the correct localization mode if the browser language does not correspond to the user language.

If you want, you can, in addition to that, change ReportViewer, usually located in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS<whatever>\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages\ReportViewer.aspx
```

and translate the report's paramters's labels using JavaScript.

Note: 
if you only change the culture in ReportViewer.aspx in method

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
```

then the datepickers won't work. 
Therefore, you need to run it as http-module (and if it loads resources, such as jquery-ui, you need to get the language from the refer[r]er).